# General pointers and advice in creating inventory structure?

Tags: java, data-structure, inventory

I am working on text-based Diablo-like RPG, where each weapon and armor has unique stats and names and there is a lot of overlap. Ie I can generate Silver Sword with 40 damage, but I can also generate Silver sword with 20 damage. So those items can't obviously be stored as one value. I am thinking of storing the items in multidimensional array where one column would store weapon name and the other column would be used for storing the damage. Same for armor etc. But I feel this may get cumbersome and spiral out of control very quickly.

Is there any other data structure I could use and have more flexible and efficient solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle inventory in an object-oriented way?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25089/how-can-i-handle-inventory-in-an-object-oriented-way)

Comment: "obviously be stored as one value" - not as one primitive value. But certainly as a class or struct instance that contains different bits of data: `{int weapon=SWORD, byte material=SILVER, uint damage=25}` etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement an inventory that stores different types of items?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178665/how-can-i-implement-an-inventory-that-stores-different-types-of-items)